# Can I make a Google Inbox bundle with attachment rules?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I'm interested in making a Google Inbox bundle that automatically grabs all messages with a certain type of attachment (eg. all MP3 files sent to me). I believe that Gmail rules had a way for this to be done, but does Google inbox have a way of doing this with their bundle feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the answer is **yes**, this is already possible.

Though the placeholder text implies that you can only do a text match, it turns out that usual search filters actually do function in that box. So, you just need to select **Includes** and give it the value `has:attachment`. In my specific example, also adding the text `filename:mp3` to the query allowed me to filter the attachments down to only MP3 attachments.

[image: Using has:attachment works in Google Inbox]

Comment: Nice find! Unfortunately this doesn't work 100%. If you have an attachment that is called mp3list.txt it will show up in your search. And it also won't find .m4a or .wav or any other type of music files. Starting down the right direction though. Helpful answer. +1

Comment: I'm not really good at the actual filters, so if anyone knows the correct filter to use here, I'll gladly update the answer (and image) with it.

Comment: I think it's something like `has:attachment AND (filename:.mp3 OR filename:.m4a OR filename:.wav)`

Comment: The dot doesn't seem to make a difference, I tried searching for `has:attachment filename:.mix` (just because I had a file with mix in the name in a recent attachment), it still showed even though it's a zip-file. So `.mp3` would probably still show the "mp3list.txt"-file.

Answer (score 1):

No. (But it must be on Google's radar for the future.)

When you create a bundle, there are limited options for how to sort as shown below:

[image]

(Includes and excludes mean text exclusively.)